# How to download internet games

Tags: downloads

I want to know how to download games that are not on the store. It will not work when I click on the application

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is to broadly phrased. Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/376205/edit) and give us an example we can work with.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu Software Centre ,then choose the game you want to install, click install button.

Answer (score 0):

If a game is not in the store, then please contact the game publisher for instructions. It would also be very nice if you edited your question to add the name of the game and the file (with extension if any) you tried to use to launch with.